# React Component vote up and down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create a react component with an input and 2 buttons.

Where the input starts with a defined number in it says 25.

Let I have a button which makes the count -1 and another button which makes the count +1.

This is where I am:

```
import React from 'react';

export class VoteUpDown extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input value="25" />
        <button className="countUp">UP</button>
        <button className="countDown">DOWN</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do this as a react component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't need any serialization of votes, and you just want a component that starts at 0 and increments/decrements from there, here's a simple example:

```
import React from 'react';

export class VoteUpDown extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      score: 0,
    };

    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.score}</div>
        <button className="countUp" onClick={this.increment}>UP</button>
        <button className="countDown" onClick={this.decrement}>DOWN</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  increment() {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1,
    });
  }

  decrement() {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score - 1,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @JakeBrown777 Try it now? Not sure if my having forgotten the `super()` call might be part of it.